# SSIS Variable SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to create a SSIS variable to display yesterday's date (today -1) in the following format: 25-Mar-2014

Comment: So then create one... I'm not entirely sure what the question is.

Comment: you are not showing your attempts

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: Here OP read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141719.aspx).

Comment: Also why do you care what the format is? A date is a date is a date. Display layer is where you change the format.

Answer (score 0):

In [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) the best thing you can do is

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()), 106),' ','-')
```

---

In [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) you have `FORMAT` function that lets you do what ever you want.

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()),'dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

or to make it even simpler

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE()-1,'dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

Comment: *Best*? What about just using a Variable with the appropriate expression set?

Comment: Why go all the way to SQLServer to get the date for an SSIS package?

Comment: The following expression is providing the correct date but incorrect format of 2014-03-25                                                                -                                                                          (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())) + "-"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())), 2) + "-"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())), 2)         .                                                                        I need 25-Mar-2014